# Authorization problem with DirectoryEntry and ActiveDirectorySecurity

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I am writing a class to set or remove access rules to protect or unprotect objects from accidental removal, using `ActiveDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule` and `ActiveDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule`.

My class works fine if I provide the username and password of an admin account to the `DirectoryEntry` (which I don't want to do), but if I don't provide username and password it throws an error

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A constraint violation occurred

My default account however can change the protect object flag using the Active Directory Users and Computers app without any problems.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace test123
{
    internal class Test124
    {
        internal static void RemoveAccidentialProtection()
        {
            string dn = "CN=XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX";

            using (DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XXX:nnn/" + dn))
            {
                IdentityReference everyOneAccount = new NTAccount("Everyone").Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); //S - 1 - 1 - 0
                ActiveDirectoryAccessRule objAce = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyOneAccount, ActiveDirectoryRights.Delete | ActiveDirectoryRights.DeleteTree, AccessControlType.Deny);
                ent.ObjectSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(objAce);
                ent.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your application running as a console app, a WinForm app, an ASP.Net app?

Comment: This is running as a console app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a post that says `DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges` defaults to setting ownership information which isn't allowed for regular users, so you need to set `DirectoryEntry` to only write the ACL changes. Put the following line just before the call to `CommitChanges`:

```
ent.Options.SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Dacl;
```

Comment: Yep, this is it. I was able to replicate this and this is what fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I did not find that in hours of searching.